# Problems with Multiindex from pd.Crosstab when appending non present row data

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, crosstab

Morning All,

Happy Friday. I have some excel output which shows `Client`, their `Sector` and the counts of their `Result` via a crosstab command. This works well:

```
dfAll_Clients = {'All_Client': ['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE','FFF'],
                'City': ['SY','LN','NY','TO','TK','LA']}
dfAll_Clients = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dfAll_Clients)
df = {  'Client': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA',
                 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB','BBB','BBB','BBB',
                 'CCC',
                'DDD','DDD','DDD','DDD','DDD','DDD','DDD','DDD','DDD','DDD'],
        'Sector': ['GOV', 'GOV', 'CORP',
                 'GOV', 'GOV', 'GOV', 'GOV','CORP','CORP','CORP',
                 'GOV',
                 'GOV','GOV','GOV','GOV','GOV','GOV','GOV','GOV','GOV','CORP'],
        'Result': ['Covered', 'Customer Reject', 'Customer Timeout',
               'Dealer Reject','Dealer Timeout','Done','Tied Covered','Tied Done','Tied Traded Away','No RFQ',
               'No RFQ',
               'Covered','Customer Reject','Customer Timeout','Dealer Reject','Dealer Timeout','Done','Tied Covered','Tied Done','Tied Traded Away','No RFQ']
      }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
# print(df)

vals = ['Covered',
'Customer Reject',
'Customer Timeout',
'Dealer Reject',
'Dealer Timeout',
'Done',
'No RFQ',
'Tied Covered',
'Tied Done',
'Tied Traded Away',
'Traded Away']

df = (pd.crosstab([df.Client,
                  df.Sector],
                 df.Result,
                 margins=True,
                 margins_name='Total_Result_Per_Client')
        .drop('Total_Result_Per_Client')
        .reindex(vals + ['Total_Result_Per_Client'], axis=1, fill_value=0))
# Total Priced Back = (All RFQ's - Dealer Reject - Dealer_Timeout) / All RFQ's
df['Total_Priced_Back'] = (df['Total_Result_Per_Client']- df['Dealer Reject'] - df['Dealer Timeout']) / (df['Total_Result_Per_Client'])
# Hit_Rate = (Done + Tied Done) / Total RFQ's less Customer Reject and Customer Timeout
df['Hit_Rate'] = (df['Done'] + df['Tied Done']) / (df['Total_Result_Per_Client']- df['Customer Reject'] - df['Customer Timeout'])
# Populate any nulls due to 0/0
df = df.fillna(0)
# Format Pct cols
decimals2 = 2
df['Total_Priced_Back'] = df['Total_Priced_Back'].apply(lambda x: round(x * 100, decimals2)).astype(str) + '%'
df['Hit_Rate'] = df['Hit_Rate'].apply(lambda x: round(x * 100, decimals2)).astype(str) + '%'
print (df)
df.to_excel('C:\Temp\Out_Data_EOM_Key_Clients_Corp.xlsx')
```

The excel extract meets the requirements.

[image]

An additional request has come in to add all other possible clients which are not present in the current months data, but may be in futures months.
For each `Client` with no data add a row in the crosstab, and for each field insert; `#NA`. The final output would be:

[image]

I looked to add theses rows via:

```
# Get list of all possible clients
dfAll_Clients = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dfAll_Clients.All_Client)
new_index = tuple(list(dfAll_Clients.All_Client))
print(new_index)
# Append clients not present in current row entries
dfTemp = df.reindex(new_index, fill_value=0)
print(dfTemp)
```

The issue is that results of the crosstab are multiindexed. I tried flattening the crosstab output with `df = df.stack([0]).reset_index()` but this changed the structure completely and deviates from the final output entirely. I now get `TypeError: Expected tuple, got str`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `reindex`

```
#here E and F (l) you can get it by 

cond = dfAll_Clients.All_Client.isin(df.index.get_level_values(0))
l = dfAll_Clients.loc[~cond,'All_Client'].unique().tolist()
l = [(x, None)for x in l]
df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index.tolist()+l))
```

Comment: Hi@BEN_YO. That works but it's hard coded. The list of all Clients is dynamic and can change from day to day. Thats why I dynamically assign the clients to a list via  new_index = tuple(list(dfAll_Clients.All_Client))

Comment: @PeterLucas I have adding the dynamic way as well

Comment: Ah ok, checking one sec

Comment: thats perfect. Thanks man. That was doing my head in.

Comment: Hi @BEN_YO. When I applied to live data there is a small issue. The appended clients create new columns. If you update the code above from A to AAA, B to BBB, C to CCC...F to FFF you'll see the output

Comment: @PeterLucas what output ?

Comment: I updated the question above. If the Client has more than one character in it's name , each character is split into separate columns. If you rn the above code again you'll see the issue

Comment: Output in ('C:\Temp\Out_Data_EOM_Key_Clients_Corp.xlsx')

Comment: Hi @BEN_YO. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @PeterLucas I tried change , output looks fine

Comment: oh...sorry, checking again.

Comment: All good!!! Somehow I ommited the l = [(x, None) for x in l] which caused the splitting. Any way to add the column headers 'Client'' and 'Sector' to the first two columns of the Excel output? They appear to be getting ommitted

Comment: @PeterLucas df = df.rename_axis(None)

Comment: Thanks @BEN_YO. Everything is working thanks.